# Get a Partial Class to show using EntityDataSource

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, visual-studio-2012, partial-classes

I have an entity object student, which has properties StudentID and StudentName. I have a partial class Student which uses a service to find that student's current school. An EntityDataSource fills up the grid just fine, accept for the school. If I watch the RowDataBound event of the grid, I can watch it go to StudentModel.Designer.cs and get the StudentID and StudentName. But it does not get the school. This makes sense, because school is not part of the entity object - but, can I even get the school custom property while using an EntityDataSource?

I've been doing some research, and it seems I need to use the ContextCreating event in order to complete my object?

Before, I was adding the school during the RowDataBound event, but I want to be able to sort on school - so that is the reason I am trying to figure this out.

I'm not sure if I'm close to the solution... or this can't be done at all and I should do all my data binding in code behind?

Here is code:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="StudentGroupEntityDataSource" 
ContextTypeName="GearUp.Data.StudentGroupEntities" OnContextCreating="StudentGroupEntityDataSource_ContextCreating"                               OnContextCreated="StudentGroupEntityDataSource_ContextCreated"
EnableFlattening="False" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" 
EntitySetName="StudentGroupMembers" 
OrderBy="it.FullName" 
Where="it.GroupID IN {@ID}">
<WhereParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter DbType="Guid" Name="ID" ControlID="StudentGroupDropDown"
         PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
 </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>

public partial class StudentGroupMember
{
private string _school;
public string School
{
    get
    {
        if (_school == null)
        {
            StudentServiceClient clientStudent = new StudentServiceClient();
            var studentDetail = clientStudent.RetrieveStudentDetail(this.StudentID.ToString());
            _school = studentDetail.SchoolName;
        }
        return _school;
    }
}
```

}